# ASP.NET Web API with MVC: Attribute routes ignored in class libraries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing an MVC application which makes use of plugins. I need to support using Web API from those plugins. I have it working (including Dependency Injection with Autofac as well). However, it seems like Attribute routing is completely ignored from the class libraries (plugins or any other assembly). For example, I have a test plugin specified as such:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/cms/test")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
```

When browsing to /api/cms/test, I get the following error:

**"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '[my site]:30863/api/cms/test'.No type was found that matches the controller named 'cms'."**

When I remove "cms", it works because it is then using the default route. Obviously this is not adequate, because I will very likely have multiple controllers with the same name (in different assemblies) and therefore need a unique route to each of them.

I inspected the Route Collection in `System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes` as well to confirm and the route is indeed missing.

Is there anyone who can tell me why the attribute routes are being ignored for class libraries and if there's a workaround?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Kiran for the comment about the Route attribute; I did notice my error with forgetting the `[Route("")]` attribute on the controller which is to be used along with the `[RoutePrefix]` attribute. I added that and now attribute routing works fine. However, I still cannot have 2 controllers with the same name, even though they are in different assemblies. After doing some research it seems that this is a known issue - not just with different assemblies, but different namespaces in general. I tried to implement a solution from here:

http://shazwazza.com/post/multiple-webapi-controllers-with-the-same-name-but-different-namespaces/

The problem with this is that now the `DataTokens` is null AND read-only! So it is no longer a viable solution to this problem. Hoping someone else has a solution to this problem.

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to Kiran for his mention about route constraints. However, that still doesn't solve my problem. What I am looking for is a way to allow multiple controllers to have the same name whether they be in separate areas, separate namespaces or both.. whatever.. The problem with this is that the underlying Web API implementation looks up controllers by name using an `IDictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor>` variable to store such information. You can see this if you look at the source code for `DefaultHttpControllerSelector`. So, at first I thought maybe I just need to inherit this class and override `GetControllerMapping()` because the calling code in the internal class, `AttributeRoutingMapper` doesn't care about the keys in that dictionary at all... it only looks at the values. So at first I thought I could override this and use the full name of the controller (including namespace) as the key, so we can get them all in there. However, it is not that easy.. for a couple of reasons, not least of which is the fact that `AttributeRoutingMapper` is not the only class to call `GetControllerMapping()`.

So it looks to be a lot of work to get what I need done; if is it even possible at all. I will be starting a bounty; 100 points to anyone who can provide a fully working solution or who can provide enough info for me to start a solution myself.

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, looks like the order of routes are not correct...looks like your request is being matched by a conventional route (ex: `api/{controller}`) rather than the attribute route...as you know route order matters...so make sure to have attribute routes register before conventional routes as they are more specific...

Also note that `RoutePrefix` attribute alone doesn't add routes to the route table, but the attribute `Route` does...

I am guessing you are hosting your application in IIS?

Comment: +1 for the note about `[Route]`. Thanks. Please see my edit above.

Comment: In general, Web API doesn't inherently support same controller name across namespaces...you would need to have different names for your controllers...an example using this approach: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/RoutingConstraintsSample/ReadMe.txt

Comment: Thanks, Kiran. This issue doesn't really make Web API a nice, pluggable architecture though... I will look at that link you sent and see if there's any customizing I can do to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: I had a look at the route constraints, but unfortunately that doesn't do what I need. That allows 2 controllers to have the same route. If you take that example in the link you sent and move the controllers to different folders and rename them both to have the same name, the sample doesn't work anymore. What I need is to have 2 controllers with the same name; not 2 controllers with the same route.